# Kotlin - How can a math function be graphically plotted using GraphView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-graphview

I have the following function, well it is the formula of the normal distribution and my goal is to graph it using the GraphView library.
Well, I have the following:

- Id --  **plot**

> code kotlin

```java
class ExampleActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var series1: LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example)

        series1 = LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>()

        val media = 8.0  
        val sd = 2.0  

        fun linspace(start: Double, stop: Double, num: Int) = Array(num) { start + it * ((stop - start) / (num - 1)) }

        val x1 = linspace(media - 3*sd, media + 3*sd, 10)
        val normal = NormalDistribution(media,sd)

        for (i in x1){
            val y = normal.cumulativeProbability(i)
            series1.appendData(DataPoint(i,y),false,x1.size)
        }
        plot.viewport.isXAxisBoundsManual = true
        plot.viewport.setMaxX(20.0)
        plot.viewport.isYAxisBoundsManual = true
        plot.viewport.setMaxY(2.0)
        //plot.viewport.isScalable = true
        plot.addSeries(series1)
    }
}
```

result
[image: reference]

this is very strange, in python I used the same and the result is more complete, I show you.

> code python

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import math

mu = 8
sigma = 2
x = np.linspace(mu - 3*sigma, mu + 3*sigma, 10)
print(np.linspace(mu - 3*sigma, mu + 3*sigma, 10))
plt.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma))
plt.show()
```

result python
[image: referente python]

> **Info**

**code kotlin**
`val x1 = linspace(media - 3*sd, media + 3*sd, 10)`

==

**code Python**
`x = np.linspace(mu - 3*sigma, mu + 3*sigma, 10)`

Can you help me please, what do I need to add?

Comment: Hey did you ever figure this out? is there a gist? I'm having a similar Issue and to see your code would really help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the python example is plotting the `.pdf` "probability density function" while the kotlin example is plotting the `.cumulativeProbability` which is essentially the integral of the PDF. Most likely you'll want to use the [`.density`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/NormalDistribution.html#density(double)) method instead.

Comment: ohh, tank you  *@mjhm*